# How can I change my output in this scenario?

Tags: python, list

So I made this code and its great, but once again the problem is that my output has a 'none' under it. How do I change it. btw, my code is this..

```
def up_and_down(k):
    return (*range(1, k), *range(k, 0, -1))

def diamond(k):
    pad = '#'
    fill = '*'
    w = (2 * k) - 1
    for i in up_and_down(k):
        print(f'{fill * len(up_and_down(i)):{pad}^{w}}')

print(diamond(k))

def triangle(k):
    w = (2 * k) - 1
    pad = '#'
    fill = '*'
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        print(f'{fill * len(up_and_down(i)):{pad}^{w}}')
print(triangle(k))
```

and my output prints out...

```
######*######
#####***#####
####*****####
###*******###
##*********##
#***********#
*************
#***********#
##*********##
###*******###
####*****####
#####***#####
######*######
None
######*######
#####***#####
####*****####
###*******###
##*********##
#***********#
*************
None
```

How can I make sure that the image is RETURNED and 'none' doesn't appear under when I use the PRINT statement either??
Btw, I need to use print because its a requirement placed by my professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you described (i.e., need to use `print`), you need to *return* a string, and then print that string outside the function.

```py
def up_and_down(k):
    return (*range(1, k), *range(k, 0, -1))

def diamond(k):
    pad = '#'
    fill = '*'
    w = (2 * k) - 1
    return '\n'.join(f'{fill * len(up_and_down(i)):{pad}^{w}}' for i in up_and_down(k))

def triangle(k):
    w = (2 * k) - 1
    pad = '#'
    fill = '*'
    return '\n'.join(f'{fill * len(up_and_down(i)):{pad}^{w}}' for i in range(1, k+1))

k = 10
print(diamond(k))
print(triangle(k))
```

Without an explicit `return`, a function returns `None`. So in your original code, `print(diamond(k))` would be like `print(None)`, which is the reason why you see `None`.

If you can't use `\n` for a reason I can't understand (but apparently due to your instructor's preference), use the following `return`s instead (to return a generator of lines, instead of one single multi-line string):

```py
return (f'{fill * len(up_and_down(i)):{pad}^{w}}' for i in up_and_down(k))
return (f'{fill * len(up_and_down(i)):{pad}^{w}}' for i in range(1, k+1))
```

respectively, and then print the output using

```py
for line in diamond(k):
    print(line)
for line in triangle(k):
    print(line)
```

Comment: is it possible to not use control characters??

Comment: ur code works, but I can't use control characters when doing this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by control characters. If you mean `\n`, then maybe you can return a list of strings, and then loop over those lines to print the lines.

Comment: yea i mean \n. Can u edit ur code so that I can understand how to return the list of strings?? because I dont really understand it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check it.